# How to convert Joda-Time DateTime to java.util.Date and vice versa?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, java.util.date

Is it possible to do that? If yes, then how do I do the conversion from [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and vice versa?

Comment: Have you seen Joda [DateTime constructors](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29)? Is there one u think might be appropriate?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

To convert [Java `Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to [Joda `DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html):-

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
```

And vice versa:-

```
Date dateNew = dateTime.toDate();
```

With `TimeZone`, if required:-

```
DateTime dateTimeNew = new DateTime(date.getTime(), timeZone);
Date dateTimeZone = dateTime.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(timeZone).toDate();
```

Comment: Your conversion to `DateTime` uses the system default time zone - you should say that explicitly. And your conversion which *does* use a time zone takes the start of the day, which is an odd choice IMO. A `DateTime` already *knows* the time zone, so it's odd to want to change it - it makes much more sense to specify the zone when converting *from* `Date` *to* `DateTime`.

Comment: `java.utiL.Date` does not actually know about a `java.util.TimeZone`. So you'll have to get the `TimeZone` in a separate variable if you need it too, like this : `TimeZone zone = dateTime.getZone().toTimeZone();`

Answer (score 6):

You haven't specified which type within Joda Time you're interested in, but:

```
Instant instant = ...;
Date date = instant.toDate();
instant = new Instant(date);
// Or...
instant = new Instant(date.getTime());
```

Neither `Date` nor `Instant` are related to time zones, so there's no need to specify one here.

It doesn't make sense to convert from `LocalDateTime` / `LocalDate` / `LocalTime` to `Date` (or vice versa) as that would depend on the time zone being applied.

With `DateTime` you can convert *to* a `Date` without specifying the time zone, but to convert from `Date` to `DateTime` you should specify the time zone, or it will use the system default time zone. (If you really *want* that, I'd specify it explicitly to make it clear that it's a deliberate choice.)

For example:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
Date date = ...;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date.getTime(), zone);
```

Comment: `LocalTime` really helps with simplifying code when interacting with `java.util.Date` and when doing tests. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**To Convert from Java Date to Joda Time of Date:**

To convert from Date to DateTime time zone needed to be specified.
To convert from java.util Date to Joda Time of Date you just need to pass the java.util Date and time zone to the constructor of Joda Time of Date.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();// Gets the default time zone.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date.getTime(), dtz);
```

**To Convert from Joda Time of Date to Java Date:**

For the reverse case Joda DateTime has a method `toDate()` which will return the java.util Date.

```
DateTime jodaDate = new DateTime();
java.util.Date date = jodaDate.toDate();
```

For More Details [Visit Here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)