# Time as a string parser in java

Tags: java, string, parsing

Is there any libraries that is able to take a string such as 5d 1h 2m 15s and add it to a java date / java Calendar?

ie a system property will be set as 5d 1h 2m 15s

We will read in the system property and add this amount of time to the current date.

Otherwise I will have to implement this as a long in milliseconds.

Comment: Hey take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min

Comment: Also see "Parsing Strings into Dates" at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

Comment: **Search Stack Overflow** for *ISO 8601, duration, Period, and PnYnMnDTnHnMnS*. This topic has been addressed many times. The java.time classes have support for both parsing and generating such strings.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need a bit of parsing to extract the component element but Joda-Time's duration should help you out

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html

If you are using Java8 joda-time's concept were integrated so no need to external dependencies

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html

once you have a duration adding it to the current date time should be trivial

Java8 and jodaTime

```
Instant ajustedTime = Instant.now().plus(yourDurationInstance);
```

you can convert to and from Java's date pretty easily, others have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333320/how-to-convert-joda-time-to-date-of-java-util-date-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Instant.now isn't found in Joda 2.6. Is there a alternative for 2.6?

Comment: Should be there as it has been introduced in 2.0: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html#now()